# Write a program to input two numbers (whose summation are less than 10) from user and display the summation of them in the next line

Tags: emu8086

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg1 db "Enter The First Number : $"
msg2 db ,0dh,0ah,"Enter The Second umber : $"
msg3 db ,0dh,0ah,"SUM of Entered Numbers = $"
num1 db ?;
num2 db ?,;
ans db ?,"$"
.code  
main proc 

mov ax,@data            ;initiaize ds
mov ds,ax  
mov dx,offset msg1      ;load and display msg1
mov ah,09
int 21h
mov ah,1h               ;read first initial
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov num1,al 
mov dx,offset msg2      ;load and display msg2
mov ah,9
int 21h
                        ;read second initial
mov ah,1h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov num2,al
mov dx,offset msg3
mov ah,9                ;load and display msg3
int 21h
mov al,num1             ;add num1 and num2
add al,num2 
add al,30h              ;moves value into ans
mov ans,al
mov dx,offset ans       ;load and display msg3
mov ah,9
int 21h
end main
```

Write a program to input two numbers (whose summation are less than 10) from user and display the summation of them in the next line. Note: No need to consider the conditions for input numbers. Sample Execution: Enter the first number: 3 Enter the second number: 5 Summation of 3 and 5 is 8
UNABLE TO show result like Summation of 3 and 5 is 8

Answer (score 0):

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg1 db "Enter The First Number : $"
msg2 db 0dh,0ah,"Enter The Second umber : $"
msg3 db 0dh,0ah,"SUM of Entered Numbers = $"
num1 db ?
num2 db ?
ans db ?,"$"
.code  
main:
mov ax,@data            ;initiaize ds
mov ds,ax  
mov dx,offset msg1      ;load and display msg1
mov ah,09
int 21h
mov ah,1h               ;read first initial
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov [num1],al 
mov dx,offset msg2      ;load and display msg2
mov ah,9
int 21h
                        ;read second initial
mov ah,1h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov [num2],al
mov dx,offset msg3
mov ah,9                ;load and display msg3
int 21h
mov al,num1             ;add num1 and num2
add al,num2 
add al,30h              ;moves value into ans
mov [ans],al
mov dx,offset ans       ;load and display msg3
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
end main
```

mov [num2], al

mov [num1], al

mov [ans], al

don't use label directly

[image]